# How correct redirect access that are causing Let's Encrypt to not secure my website?

Tags: security-certificate, openssl

I have successfully installed Let's Encrypt SSL certificates on my server after going though some issues.

You can view my issues being treated by their awesome team in there official site:
https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/i-ran-this-command-certbot-auto-and-got-this-error-no-vhost-exists-with-servername-or-alias/26136

Problem is that my website, which is a **vBulletin Forum** due to some issue is not applying the security to it!

Here is what I was told:

> The "problem" here is that you have a redirect/rewrite rule
>   redirecting https to http, pay attention to below output from your
>   server, you will see a Location header redirecting

```
https://www.iforumelite.com to http://www.iforumelite.com/forum.php?s=7c01b777432f8d66d2f927f5d848aa88
```

He mentioned:

> Note: The redirect/rewrite rule could be in your apache conf, on
>   .htaccess files used by your site or even the forum that you are using
>   could be redirecting it.

I checked all of it and found nothing. Here is my .htaccess file for the site in question:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If you are having problems or are using VirtualDocumentRoot, uncomment this line and set it to your vBulletin directory.
# RewriteBase /forum/

# If you are having problems with the rewrite from content/ to content.php, uncomment this line to turn MultiViews off.
# Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Forum
RewriteRule ^threads/.* showthread.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^forums/.* forumdisplay.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^members/.* member.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^blogs/.* blog.php [QSA]
RewriteRule ^entries/.* entry.php [QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# MVC
RewriteRule ^(?:(.*?)(?:/|$))(.*|$)$ $1.php?r=$2 [QSA]

# Check MVC result
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]

# Set PHP handler to application/x-httpd-php on Fri Nov 13 19:59:33 MST 2015.
#AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: I suspect you have not informed your CMS of the URL change, since most content management systems use PHP redirects from a set base URL normally set in the database or a config file. Login to your dashboard and check your settings within and perhaps the config file that is used to connect to the database.

Comment: how can I mark your comment as my answer!  :)

Comment: Added as answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have not informed your CMS of the URL change, since most content management systems use PHP redirects from a set base URL normally set in the database or a config file. Login to your dashboard and check your settings within and perhaps the config file that is used to connect to the database.